# panda dataframe to numpy array using pandas.dataframe.values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame as below. I want to make it a numpy array. 
When i using df.values command it is making as numpy array but all the attributes are converted to float. I checked df.values documentation but was not helpful, can i assign same datatype of df to numpy?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
                   High          Low  ...      Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                         
2018-12-20  2509.629883  2441.179932  ...  5585780000  2467.419922
2018-12-21  2504.409912  2408.550049  ...  7609010000  2416.620117
2018-12-24  2410.340088  2351.100098  ...  2613930000  2351.100098
2018-12-26  2467.760010  2346.580078  ...  4233990000  2467.699951
2018-12-27  2489.100098  2397.939941  ...  4096610000  2488.830078
2018-12-28  2520.270020  2472.889893  ...  3702620000  2485.739990
2018-12-31  2509.239990  2482.820068  ...  3442870000  2506.850098
2019-01-02  2519.489990  2467.469971  ...  3733160000  2510.030029
```

Comment: pandas to_record?

Comment: Problem with to_records() approach is that it is creating an array with 1 dimension like ((14,) in my case , how do i same dimension as that of df

Comment: It is 1d with different `fields` for each of the df columns. That way you can have a different dtype for each field.  Look up structured array or record array.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer will go over structured array

Comment: Hi Wen,Can we access columns in np.array when we have to_record to make np.array from panda?

Comment: Access fields by name `arr['Date']`, arr['Low']`

Comment: Thanks!  hpaulj , it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with NumPy [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).
I will create a DataFrame with only 2 rows and 2 columns similar to yours to demonstrate how you can do it with any size of DataFrame.

```
import Pandas as pd
import Numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'High': [2509.629883, 2504.409912], 
                   'Volume': [5585780000, 7609010000]}, 
                  index=np.array(['2018-12-20', '2018-12-21'], dtype='datetime64'))
```

Then you create an empty NumPy array defining what datatype each column must have. In my example, I only have 2 rows so the array will only have 2 rows as following:

```
array = np.empty(2, dtype={'names':('col1', 'col2', 'col3'),
                          'formats':('datetime64[D]', 'f8', 'i8')})

array['col1'] = df.index
array['col2'] = df['High']
array['col3'] = df['Volume']
```

and, the array will look like:

```
array([('2018-12-20', 2509.629883, 5585780000),
       ('2018-12-21', 2504.409912, 7609010000)],
      dtype=[('col1', '<M8[D]'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<i8')])
```

You also can create a `np.recarray` class using command `np.rec.array`. This is almost identical with structured arrays with only one extra feature. You can access fields as attributes, i.e. `array.col1` instead of `array['col1']`. However, numpy record arrays are apparently slower than structured arrays!

Answer (score 1):

[Numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) have a uniform data type, as you can see from the documentation:

> **numpy.ndarray class numpy.ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None,**
>
> offset=0, strides=None, order=None)[source] An array object represents
> a multidimensional, **homogeneous array** of fixed-size items. An
> associated data-type object describes the format of each element in
> the array (its byte-order, how many bytes it occupies in memory,
> whether it is an integer, a floating point number, or something else,
> etc.)

When you use the df.values, it will cast all values to the most suitable datatype to keep the homogeneity.

The [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) also mentions that:

> **Notes**
>
> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit
> upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are
> mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with
> care if you are not dealing with the blocks.
>
> e.g. If the dtypes are float16 and float32, dtype will be upcast to
> float32. If dtypes are int32 and uint8, dtype will be upcast to int32.
> By numpy.find_common_type() convention, mixing int64 and uint64 will
> result in a float64 dtype.

Comment: We can have a different data type for numpy array attributes when I am using array=df.to_records()   to create numpy array I am getting different dtype of each attribute. Problem with to_records() approach is that it is creating array with 1 dimension like ((14,) in my case